# Missing Firefox Developer Edition Icon

Tags: firefox

Why is the icon for my Firefox Developer Edition browser missing from my latest version of Ubuntu?

[image: Firefox Aurora]

Comment: how did you install firefox dev, and also you can edit the desktop entry which is usaly located in /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 2):

You need to point the icon path in your .desktop:

e.g. mine:

Note that I have it installed in `/home/jorgee/Applications/firefox-dev/`

```
root@jorgee:/usr/share/applications# cat Firefox\ Developer\ Edition.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=/home/jorgee/Applications/firefox-dev/firefox-bin %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/jorgee/Applications/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/home/jorgee/Applications/firefox-dev/firefox-bin -new-window
[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/home/jorgee/Applications/firefox-dev/firefox-bin -private-window
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your icon is missing is because the icon file cannot be found. The icon for an application is specified in the `.desktop` launcher file of the applications, through the desktop entry key `icon=`. On that line, one can specify a full pathname to a specific icon file, e.g. `icon=/home/user/images/firefox-dev.png`. Alternatively, one can specify just a file name, without extension, e.g. `icon=firefox-dev`. Then, the system will find a matching icon file of type `xpm`, `png` or `jpg` searching through your `~/.local/share/icons` and `~/.icons` folders, and then through `icon` folders existing under the folders listed in the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environmental variable.

Since you installed this application manually, you took it upon yourself to have this right. Thus, make sure the icon mentioned in the `.desktop` launcher matches a file on your system as I outlined in the first paragraph.